# Firebird ODBC Windows 7 Home

Tags: windows-7, odbc, firebird

I have a Firebird 2.1.2 database running on a Windows 2003.
I already have Windows XP clients, also Windows 7 64-bit Profesional, all logged into the same Windows domain as the server and every one using ODBC connections.

But I want to connect a Windows 7 64-bit Home Basic to that Firebird database. Using Firebird Client (ODBC) I cannot open a conection to the Firebird server. I also tried FlameRobin with no success... I can get access to the shared, but not to the database.

Did anyone had this problem before? Is this because of the domain restriction of Windows 7 Home?
Is there any tool to help me diagnosing this issue?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Did you install the Firebird ODBC driver and the Firebird client libraries. Are they the same bitness (ie 64 or 32 bit), if 32 bit did you use the 32 bit ODBC Administrator to configure the DSN. Is your application 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: Hello Mark, the server is Firebird 2.1.2 32 bits. .... I checked versions and installed the 32 bits client correctly... IT WORKED!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the "reminder", it made me check consciously the installation and found the problem. thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. The bitness of the server is however irrelevant to the problem, just the bitness of all the parts on the client-side matters.

Answer (score 5):

*Answer based on my comment that solved the issue*

The most likely cause is missing libraries or incorrect bitness of various components. If your application is 32 bit, then you need to make sure that

- The ODBC driver is 32 bit
- The installed Firebird client library is 32 bit
- If you use a DSN: that the DSN is created using the 32 bit ODBC administrator

The same applies if your application is 64 bit, but then of course all components need to be 64 bit. Mismatch in bitness will simply mean that the application doesn't see the library. Of course if one of the above is missing entirely it won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `64bit ODBC` Administrator which is located in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`
Double click the `odbcad32.exe` then you will get the option to see the `Firebird` driver.